# UIWebview not persistant cookies

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uiwebview

I have 2 storyboards for my app, the use the same code, are designed the same way but one is for ipad and one is for iphone. The iPhone storyboard works fine but the iPad storyboard can't persist it's cookie when it becomes inactive(Called notification center, suspend app to background and bringing it up again, etc.) As far as i know it should work fine. Is someone willing to have a look at it and help me out? Thanks in advance!

BecomeActive:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    self.user.loggedOut = [defaults objectForKey:@"loggedOut"];
    Database* db = [[Database alloc] init];

    //Get Node from voffice
    NSString* hostStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"************?klantnaam="];
    //NSLog(@"host string:%@", hostStr);
    NSData* dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: hostStr ]];
    NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    //NSLog(@"Server output:%@", serverOutput);
    NSArray *output = [serverOutput componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
    self.nodeNummer = output[0];

    if([db checkConnection]){

        // Reset badge number to 0
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

        self.user = [db checkAppStart];
        BOOL userCheck = FALSE;

        // IF NO USER IN LOCAL DATABASE
        if(self.user != NULL){
            userCheck = TRUE;
        }

        //TRUE = mainNavigator / FALSE = loginView


        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            NSString *segueId = userCheck ? @"mainNavigator" : @"loginView";
            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPad" bundle:nil];
            UIViewController *initViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:segueId];

            if(userCheck){
                [self.window setRootViewController:initViewController];
            }
        }else{
            NSString *segueId = userCheck ? @"mainNavigator" : @"loginView";
            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
            UIViewController *initViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:segueId];

            if(userCheck){
                [self.window setRootViewController:initViewController];
            }
        }

    }

}
```

WebViewController.m

```
#import "WebViewController.h"


@interface WebViewController () 

@end

@implementation WebViewController
@synthesize vofficeWebview;
@synthesize activityIndicator;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


// DID LOAD
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [activityIndicator startAnimating];


    ad = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    db = [[Database alloc] init];


    // Pull to refresh part
    vofficeWebview.tag = 999;

    for(UIView* subview in vofficeWebview.subviews){
        if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]){
            currentScrollView = (UIScrollView*)subview;
            vofficeWebview.delegate = (id) self;
        }
    }

    PullToRefreshView *pull = [[PullToRefreshView alloc] initWithScrollView:currentScrollView];

    [pull setDelegate:self];

    pull.tag = 998;

    [currentScrollView addSubview:pull];
    [self.view addSubview:vofficeWebview];


    [vofficeWebview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [vofficeWebview setOpaque:NO];

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    // Hide nagivationBar because of the website bar
//    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
}

// DID APPEAR
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest;
    BOOL killed = [defaults boolForKey:@"appKilled"];


    NSLog(@"name:%@", ad.user.name);
    NSLog(@"version:%@", ad.user.version);
    NSLog(@"pdakey:%@", ad.user.pdaKey);

    if([db checkConnection]){

        //Get Node from voffice
        NSString* hostStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"*************?klantnaam=%@", ad.user.company];
        //NSLog(@"host string:%@", hostStr);
        NSData* dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: hostStr ]];
        NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        //NSLog(@"Server output:%@", serverOutput);
        NSArray *output = [serverOutput componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
        ad.nodeNummer = output[0];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:ad.nodeNummer forKey:@"nodeNummer"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        NSLog(@"Node nummer: %@", ad.nodeNummer);



        if(!ad.urlSaved){

            ad.urlSaved = TRUE;

            NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"***********?db=%@&logincode=%@", ad.user.version, ad.user.pdaKey];
            urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
            [defaults setBool:FALSE forKey:@"appKilled"];

        }else if (killed){

            NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"**********?db=%@&logincode=%@",ad.nodeNummer, ad.user.version, ad.user.pdaKey];
            urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
            [defaults setBool:FALSE forKey:@"appKilled"];
        }else{

            NSRange wordRange = NSMakeRange(0, 24);
            NSString* checkString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"************", ad.nodeNummer];
            NSString* savedURL = [defaults objectForKey:@"savedURL"];

            NSString* searchString = [savedURL substringWithRange:wordRange];


            if([searchString isEqualToString:checkString]){

                NSTimeInterval interval = [ad.user.lastView timeIntervalSinceNow];
                NSInteger TimeToGoToDefault = 60*60*2;
                if(interval < -TimeToGoToDefault){
                    NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"*********?db=%@&logincode=%@", ad.user.version, ad.user.pdaKey];
                    urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
                }else{
                    urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:savedURL]];
                }
            }else{

                NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://***********?db=%@&logincode=%@",ad.nodeNummer, ad.user.version, ad.user.pdaKey];
                urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

            }
        }


        [vofficeWebview loadRequest:urlRequest];
    }
}



// START LOADING
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    [self.loadingIndicator startAnimating];

}


// FINISHED LOADING
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    [self.loadingIndicator stopAnimating];

    [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];

    vofficeWebview.hidden = FALSE;

    NSString *currentURL = vofficeWebview.request.URL.absoluteString;

    NSString* afbeeldingCheckString = @"";
    NSRange pdf = [currentURL rangeOfString:@".pdf" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    NSRange worddoc = [currentURL rangeOfString:@".doc" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    NSRange worddocx = [currentURL rangeOfString:@".docx" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

    if(pdf.location != NSNotFound){
        webView.scalesPageToFit = true;
    }
    if(worddoc.location != NSNotFound){
        webView.scalesPageToFit = true;
    }
    if(worddocx.location != NSNotFound){
        webView.scalesPageToFit = true;
    }
    if(currentURL.length > 47){
        afbeeldingCheckString = [currentURL substringToIndex:47];
    }


    NSString* savedURL = [defaults objectForKey:@"savedURL"];

    NSArray* separatedSavedURL = [currentURL componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

    savedURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@%@",ad.nodeNummer, [currentURL substringFromIndex:[separatedSavedURL[0] length]]];

    NSLog(@"current URL: %@",currentURL);
    NSLog(@"saved URL: %@",savedURL);

    ad.urlSaved = savedURL;
    [defaults setObject:savedURL forKey:@"savedURL"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    NSString* leftBarButtonName = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('knop')[0].getAttribute('name')"];

    NSString* leftButtonValue = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('knop')[0].getAttribute('link')"];

    NSLog(@"leftButtonTitle:'%@'", leftBarButtonName);

    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:vofficeWebview.request.URL];
    NSDictionary* headers = [NSHTTPCookie requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies:[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]];
    [request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];

//    NSLog(@"test body:%@", leftButtonValue);


    if(leftBarButtonName != NULL && ![leftBarButtonName isEqualToString:@""] && leftBarButtonName.length != 0){
        [self changeLeftBarButton:leftBarButtonName link:leftButtonValue];
    }else{




    }


    [(PullToRefreshView*)[self.view viewWithTag:998] finishedLoading];



}


- (void)changeLeftBarButton:(NSString*)name link:(NSString*)link{

    leftButtonLink = link;

    UIBarButtonItem* leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:name style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];

    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:leftBarButtonItem];

    leftBarButtonItem.title = name;
    [leftBarButtonItem setTarget:self];
    [leftBarButtonItem setAction:@selector(changeLeftBarButtonLink)];

}

- (void)changeLeftBarButtonLink{
    NSString* URL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://*************",ad.nodeNummer, leftButtonLink];
    NSURLRequest* urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];
    [vofficeWebview loadRequest:urlRequest];
}


- (void) pullToRefreshViewShouldRefresh:(PullToRefreshView *)view{
    [(UIWebView*)[self.view viewWithTag:999] reload];

}

- (IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender{

        [vofficeWebview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.activeElement.blur()"];


}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)goBackButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [vofficeWebview goBack];
}

- (IBAction)goToDefaultButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSURLRequest *requestObj;

    NSString *defaultURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://*****/***/*****?db=%@&logincode=%@", ad.user.version, ad.user.pdaKey];
    //NSLog(@"%@", defaultURL);
    requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:defaultURL]];

    [vofficeWebview loadRequest:requestObj];
}
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [self setVofficeView:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}



@end
```

Iphone Storyboard:
http://pastebin.com/vUWX4XsD

Ipad Storyboard:
http://pastebin.com/BiSFq3LY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been solved by implementation of the correct methods. My predecessor did not use the correct methods to view certain pages